# VBA Module - Sub Procedure assistance - Copy data values only from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1

Tags: vba, excel

The problem I face at the moment is a sub-procedure within a module I have called "Update" (which has already been written) which I want to do the following;

Select the “Sheet2” sheet data (one row, A4:KL4) and copy to the “master” sheet in sequence to the data that has been recorded above it.

The sub procedure also needs to include another function of searching the “master” sheet for previous entries of the reference number and only copying the “Sheet2” row data if the reference number does not already exist.

If the reference number already exists then it then needs to check the date of the previous entry. If it’s the same date, then I want the sub procedure to overwrite what has already been saved. If the date is different, then I want the sub-procedure to add the “Sheet2” sheet to a new row.

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it. I have checked other posts and have even tried using some of the code from previous answers but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
Sub update1()
    Sheets("loading").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Current Audit").Select
    Range("J76").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AG4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("J77").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AF4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
         Range("B75").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Q4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B76").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("R4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B77").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("S4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B78").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("T4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B79").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("U4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B80").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("V4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B81").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("W4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("B82").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("X4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B83").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Y4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B84").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Z4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("B85").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AA4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B86").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AB4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B87").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AC4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("B88").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AD4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B89").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AE4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


    Range("AF5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
    Range("AG5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"

        Range("Q5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("R5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
    Range("S5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("T5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
     Range("U5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("V5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
    Range("W5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("X5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
       Range("Y5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("Z5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
     Range("AA5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("AB5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
    Range("AC5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("AD5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
      Range("AE5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"

        Range("GA5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("GE5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("GI5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("GM5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("GP5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("GR5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("GU5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("GW5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("GZ5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("HB5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("HE5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("HH5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
        Range("HK5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: This is what I have done so far on the update module - This is linked to an "Update" button within a userform. Not sure how relevant what I have done so far to this question is but here goes.. I am hoping to add the solution to the bottom of this text.

Comment: Sub update1()
Sheets("loading").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Current Audit").Select
    Range("J76").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AG4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("J77").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AF4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
         Range("B75").Select

Comment: Sorry - the last comment will make little sense. I have tried to copy the module into the comment box but it's too large so have added as much as I can. I will search the VBA tags for the code I have tried to use. Thanks Harry

Comment: This is what I have tried based on another post. I have also tried speaking with someone I know who is a programmer but they are more web based.                                        Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").range("A1")

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but I am using Excel 2010. Thanks for looking at this question!

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the code there?

Comment: Your above code has nothing to do with the your query? Show us the code that you tried and which didn't work. From where I see it, the code is very simple...

Comment: Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").range("A4")

Comment: The above post is what I have tried and failed with so far

Comment: The above code has nothing to do with your original query where you have to copy the selected range from 1 sheet into a different worksheet and to check if exists or not.

Comment: I know - I'm a completely new to VBA - I bought a book in January to try and develop a new skill and have got so far with it. I really do not know how to check if data exists or not. I was focusing on copy and paste procedure and could not get that right. I was then told about this website so thought I'd join.

Comment: This site can only help you with the code that you are stuck with. I doubt if any one will write the entire code for you. Here is one link which will help you on how to search for something in Excel using `.Find` http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thanks for helping and the link - I'll check it out. Thanks again. Harry

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to save my data into an array first, manipulate it  and then dump the results into the new range. Arrays are easier and faster to manipulate in general.Also, it is much easier to create an array of formulas (in your case an array of:
"=IF(R[-1]C=""N/A"",""N/A"",R[-1]C*100)"

e.g.

```
Dim YourArrayContainingFormulas() As Variant
Redim YourArrayContainingFormulas(1 to 10)
For i = 1 To 10
  YourArrayContainingFormulas(i)="=YourFormula"
Next i
```

and copy it to a selected range like this:

```
With ActiveCell
  Range(.Offest(0,0),.Offset(0,9)).Value=YourArrayContainingFormulas
End With
```